# Что выводит yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть база данных по имени u13461 ( в ней есть таблица result и 3 поля `id`, `date`, `result`)
Создаю файл модели **results.php** (В папке models)
Пишу тут:

```
namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class results extends ActiveRecord
{
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;

    /**
     * @return string название таблицы, сопоставленной с этим ActiveRecord-классом.
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'result';

    }
}
```

Далее в контролере **SiteController** пишу:

```
use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\EntryForm;
use app\models\results;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
         $query = results::find()->all();
            return $this->render('index', [
                'query' => $query
            ]);
        }
}
```

В views файле **index.php** пишу:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($query);
echo "</pre>";
```

В итоге, по мимо данных из базы я получаю еще куча данных в непонятной структуре и данные из базы дублируются.
Почему?

Вот что показывает:

```
Array
(
    [0] => app\models\results Object
        (
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [date] => 
                    [result] => 0
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [date] => 
                    [result] => 0
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => app\models\results Object
        (
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [date] => 
                    [result] => 0
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [date] => 
                    [result] => 0
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => app\models\results Object
        (
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [date] => 
                    [result] => 0
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [date] => 
                    [result] => 0
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => app\models\results Object
        (
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [date] => 
                    [result] => 0
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [date] => 
                    [result] => 0
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Что выводит при echo $query['id']?

Comment: Выводит просто 1

Comment: попробуйте перезалить папку Vendor. Я у себя проверил. Выводит все как нужно. Ничего не дублируется.

Comment: 1. Работаю без композера
2. Перезалил

когда добавляю -> asArray, то уже выводит 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [date] => 2016-04-15
            [result] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 2016-04-14
            [result] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [date] => 2016-04-13
            [result] => 1
        )

)
1

Comment: Вот и все) Теперь все верно

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модель, `results` наследуется от `ActiveRecord`, а он в свою очередь `BaseActiveRecord`, а тот от `Model` и `ActiveRecordInterface`.

А `Model` наследут `extends Component implements IteratorAggregate, ArrayAccess, Arrayable` и т.д.
Соответственно, при запросе получается мы создаем экземпляр класса `results` и вызываем какие-то методы. А так как экземпляр класса содержит в себе методы и поля родительских классов, то при `print_r` вы информацию о них и видите.

Если посмотреть эти классы, например `Model`, то увидите

```
 /**
     * @var array validation errors (attribute name => array of errors)
     */
    private $_errors;
    /**
     * @var ArrayObject list of validators
     */
    private $_validators;
    /**
     * @var string current scenario
     */
    private $_scenario = self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT;
```

или `class Component`

```
 /**
     * @var array the attached event handlers (event name => handlers)
     */
    private $_events = [];

    ...
```

Как раз то, что и видим на дисплее. Они не берутся из базы, это всего лишь наследуемые поля. Считайте это отладочной информацией

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как все вывести без отладочной информации?

Comment: ну видимо `-> asArray,` после `find` =) То есть `results::find()->asArray()->all()` Но это я так грубо обозвал отладочной информацией. Ибо называть все унаследованные поля отладочной информацией как-то перебор))

Answer (score 1):

ты получаешь модель. В модели у тебя есть:

1. Аттрибуты, текущие значения твоих полей.
2. _old_attributes  - Если ты изменил модель - но не сделал save, ты всегда можешь увидеть оригинальнае данные в этом массиве.
3. _errors - ошибки модели, после валидации
4. _related - связи с другими моделями
   и пр. пр.

Все это можно найти в официальной документации
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html

Это не просто "отладочная информация", этим можно и нужно пользоваться

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте добавить к сказанному.
Посмотрите еще про датапровайдеры - они могут позволить гибко настроить отображение в листинге
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html

если с этим типом датапровайдера использовать виджет ListView 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html
то вы сможете буквально в две строки "очистить" от вывода "ненужных" полейи выводитьтолько вам нужные.Очень гибкий инструмент на самом деле.
К примеру

```
<?php 
$resultsProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Result::find(),
            'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 3,
            ],
        ]);
    echo ListView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $resultsProvider,
         'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
         'itemView' => '_result-item-view',            
    ]);
?>
```

и в шаблоне вью для каждой выводимой модели _result-item-view вы можете вывести как вам угодно - к примеру

```
<p class="clearfix">
    <?=Html::encode($model->getAttribute('id'))?>
    <?=Html::encode($model->getAttribute('result'))?>
</p>
```